# Taking a level in Airship Pilot instead of level 3 Rogue

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew, prestige-class

I'm a 1st level Rogue in 3.5e. Instead of taking 3rd level Rogue, I want to take a level of [Airship Pilot](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Airship_Pilot_(3.5e_Prestige_Class)). I'll be playing Sky Pirate style captain. I know that the prerequisites are challenging for a 2nd level Rogue. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 8):

### [Qualifying for this class](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Airship_Pilot_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29)

This class has 5 piece of prerequisites.

1. BAB: +3.
2. Knowledge (Engineering) 8 ranks
3. Profession (Pilot) 6 ranks
4. Use Rope 4 ranks.
5. Must possess an airship worth at least 10,000 gp. The means of
   acquisition are irrelevant. You may also require levels in certain
   classes depending on your Captain style chosen.

All of these prerequisites need to be met before you start aquiring the level you're taking the first level of Airship Pilot, no taking anything from level X to meet the qualifications for taking Airship Pilot for level X.

So:
1) BAB of +3 inforces a minimum hit dice of 3. This can be aquired from 4 levels in rogue, and unless you're retraining away all of your rogue levels, level four is the earliest you can meet this requirement.
2-4) Your skills are capped at Hit Dice +3, so you can't meet the 8 Knowledge (Engineering) ranks until level 5 (barring expensive options, such as wasting a feat.)
5) You need a ship... this can be done by a stealth and ballsy enough first level rogue, so it's not a mechanical hinderence, but the DM can use it to keep you out of the PrC as long as he likes.

In short, you need to take 5 levels of rogue before your can take one level of Airship Pilot.

Comment: *In short, you need to take 5 levels of rogue* => nope, you need 5 HD. Those HDs may come either from racial levels or class levels, and may come from multiple classes. It's important in that it allows some variety even before taking the 1st level of PrC.

Comment: Fair point. I was righting this base on the question "How soon can a Rogue enter the Sky Pirate PrC?"

Answer (score 5):

## First, this is a homebrew class

Note that this is not an official class; you will need to talk to your DM about that. dandwiki.com has a notorious reputation for poor homebrew, but this one seems reasonable enough; a bit on the weak side, but not awfully so for a rogue.

There is an official class with similar stylings in *Explorer’s Handbook*, the windwright captain. This class seems slightly better if you have no magic for windwright captain to progress.

## Second, you *cannot* qualify for this class at 2nd level

The class requires 8 ranks in Knowledge (engineering), which you cannot get until 5th level. Thus, the first level of this class you can take is at 6th. The BAB +3 requirement is also problematic for a rogue, since your BAB is only +1 and won’t be +3 until 4th level.

Answer (score 2):

### This class is Homebrew content, and isn't supported by the 3.5 SRD or by Wizards of the Coast.

Where D&D Wiki includes an official Wizards-produced class from the SRD, it will be marked as part of the "SRD" or "System Reference Document".

The rest are homebrew classes, which may or may not have severe balance issues or may be completely under- or over-powered in comparison to other classes. One thing to note is that if you show up at your table with a level in a class no one has ever heard of you're going to get some really funny looks. Make sure your DM is okay with you taking a level in a homebrew class before showing up at the table with a level in it.

### This class uses 3.0 skills, but could still be used in 3.5 with some changes.

The skill Celestial Navigation that you get at entering at level 1 of this prestige class gives you a +10 Bonus to the skill Intuit Direction, which is a 3.0 skill, not a 3.5 skill. Intuit Direction was converted over to the Survival skill in 3.5. This class doesn't seem to have been written for exact version you're playing, so that's something to keep in mind when considering a level dip into the class.

If you wish to use this in a 3.5 campaign, you're going to have to change the points in Intuit Direction to points in the Survival skill, which that skill has been changed to in the newer editions of Dungeons and dragons.

### Predict Weather

Normally for skill results, beating the score by at least 5 gives you additional information about the check you're attempting or the monster that you're attempting to identify, the fact that it gives you an hours information based on a check exceeding the DC by one is a bit overtuned, and could lead to you knowing a lot of information or trivializing a possible encounter if your DM has a storm or some encounter planned.

### Awaken Airship

It's a supernatural ability that turns your ship into an intelligent magical item. This can be an amazing thing for great roleplaying fluff or it can be an absolutely awful thing if you have a DM that happens to antagonize you or shuffle you between quests that he's planned.

A DM determines when an intelligent magical item fights back against its owners will so this could be either a blessing or a curse. If you fail the opposed check against your magical item you lose control of your character. Your item decides how you act, which could end up killing you.

In other words, Buyer Beware. This skill may or may not screw you if  you take the last level of this class.

### You have to be at least level 5 to take a level in this class

Based on the information written in the class, and based on the fact that your maximum ranks in a skill is limited to (Hit dice+3), it will be at least 5th level in Rogue before you have enough ranks in Knowledge(Engineering) to get into the class. However, in the event that your DM DOES happen to allow it, a one level dip could be very beneficial in the class provided IF you're a rogue and you're willing to burn so many skill points to get into the class.

The most valuable features in the class that you can get is the 1st, 3rd, and 5th level bonuses, and the Ship Upgrades available every level you gain in the class that can't really be attained otherwise. The intelligent ship can be either a flaw or a boon based on how your DM chooses to roleplay your ship, but I'd avoid multiple levels as you'd be taking away from other good prestige classes you could take. For a one level dip you get another Sneak attack die, which is a pretty good trade, along with the bonus to saves and the Animal companion, its very much worth it to take a one level dip. Any more than that would be a waste of experience points.

Comment: The detail you're going into seems odd. "This class is 3.0" - you say they should bear this in mind, but what about that is significant (beyond needing to convert one skill)? You express caution, but don't say why it might be needed. "Predict Weather" - Why is this a problem? What do the words *"legitimacy of this class as a balancing mechanism"* actually mean? (I know those words and phrases, but not in this combination.) "Awaken Airship" - Of course it's strange, but you could probably just provide a warning that an antagonistic DM will screw with you and leave it at that.